# How can I control the date labels on my x axis using the 'plot' function?

Tags: r, date, format

I am plotting data from 1st Feb 2020 to 31st Dec 2020 i.e. 11 months worth.
I have converted the x axis data from character to date format and it now shows six ticks labelled Mar, May, Jul, Sep, Nov, Jan which must be the default
I want 11 ticks labelled Feb through Dec.
I am pretty new to 'R' (obviously).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data and plot look like something this:

```r
dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-02-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day")
values <- cumsum(rnorm(length(dates)))

plot(dates, values, type = "l")
```

[image]

Then we can plot with a blank axis using `xaxt = "n"` in our plot, then add a custom axis using `axis`, setting the x axis labels with `at`

```r
plot(dates, values, type = "l", xaxt = "n")
axis.Date(1, dates, 
          at = seq(as.Date("2020-02-01"), as.Date("2020-12-01"), by = "1 month"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. Can I also put day/month on the axis so 1 Feb etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ggplot to for your data. If so you will need to format the style for the ticks. There are plenty of tutorials for this online. Here is a nice one
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/06/customizing-time-and-date-scales-in-ggplot2/

You will see `scale_x_date` here, I beleive this is what you are looking for:

`scale_x_date(date_breaks  ="1 month")`

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work using the first reply but will check this out too.  Claire